# Need to move 800GB partition to the right to make more space for Ubuntu. How long will it take in your experience?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I don't know if this is relevant on this forum.
So I have the Following Partition structure on my PC.

[image]

So, I was Going to delete the `/dev/sda3`, `/dev/sda6` and the swap Partitions and move the `/dev/sda4` to the right to make space for a larger Ubuntu Partition on the start of the disk.

In your Experience, how long will it take in Gparted? Also, what is the best way to do this? (All Data is backed up. So will it be faster to simply delete the partition and make a new one to copy 750 GB data onto it?)

[Desktop: Core i5 6500, 16 GB DDR4 RAM, a 1TB HDD and a 2 TB HDD]

The problem is that in case there is a power cut, the UPS may not be able to power it for long.

I guess I am going to delete this partition and make a new one on a new disk in ext4 and then reuse this disk later.

Comment: Looks like you use a HDD (not a SSD), so moving a partition with this large amount of data will take several hours. If your machine is a laptop, make sure your power-supply is connected to it. Deleting, recreating the partition and copying over from backup is probably faster but depends on the speed of the drive your backup is stored on. If your backup is stored on another internal HDD it should be faster, if your backup is stored on an external HDD connected via USB2.0 copying will be much slower.

Comment: @mook765 Actually it's a desktop (core i5 6500, 16GB DDR4, a 1TB HDD and another 2 TB HDD). Should I disconnect the 2 TB for this or I guess it's not necessary to do so.

Comment: Do you really need to have just one Linux partition? You could create one before the "big" partition, one after, install your system on one of them and use the other one for storage as needed.

Comment: @fkraiem Oh yes! Btw, which do you think should be the bigger one the `/root` or the `/home` ? I keep all my data on another Partition anyways. But I install a lot of programs like Android Studio, Aptana, Visual studio code, SQL Server, etc. I am going for `/root` on the 100GB and `/home` on the 30GB.

Comment: It of course depends on where you put all your stuff. If it were me, I would do it the other way around, because I put everything in my home folder except Apt-installed packages, of which I don't have many. But maybe you work differently. By the way, the "non-root" partition need not be mounted on `\home`; you can mount it anywhere you want.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed on your machine? If not or if you are going to get rid of Windows I would avoid using NTFS. If a NTFS-partition becomes corrupted it might be impossible to repair the file-system with Linux tools and you might need to use Windows to repair it in such a case. I was using NTFS without any trouble while dual-booting with Windows, but when I switched to Ubuntu single-boot I changed everything to ext4 to prevent headache.

Comment: @mook765 OK, but could you please direct me to any reliable tool to convert NTFS to ext4? Because then otherwise I am still left with making a whole 800GB new partition. I am searching for tools for now.

Comment: @fkraiem Yes, basically, i was thinking of mounting `/home` on the 30GB and everything else under`/` on the 100 GB. My thinking was that, if I ever need any more space in home, I could mount other NTFS Partitions under `Downloads` or `Documents` or such.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that can convert from NTFS to ext4, I just made new partitions and copied data. I often loose power due to the area I live and couldn't go with NTFS anymore, I had a UPS before but it exploded. Sometime I have to run fsck after a power failure, but not often. ext4 seems to be reliable and is  the native file-system which can be easily repaired when having problems. NTFS support in Linux is pretty good so far, but heavy problems can't be solved with Linux tools.

Answer (score 1):

About 2 hours with a high end HDD. However since you probably want to backup anyway it might be faster to use partclone if the file system is mostly free space.

Comment: So, I have a spare 1 tb HDD (just bought), do you think i should use partclone or some similar software to clone the 800 GB to the new drive and then use that drive instead. In terms of time taken. The problem is that in case there is a power cut, the UPS may not be able to power it for long.

Comment: @Aditya Thats exactly why partclone is much safer. Like I said though the time depends how much of the file system is used up.